# Vim/Vundle broken after reverting back to bash from zsh

Tags: bash, vim, zsh, vundle

This is the error message I get when trying to BundleInstall:

```
Shell can't be executed /bin/zsh
Error while executing "function vundle#installer#new..<SNR>37_process..vundle#installer#run..vundle#installer#install..<SNR>37_sync..<SNR>37_system":
Line    1:
E484: Can't open file /tmp/vfHFBSJ/8
Error while executing "function vundle#installer#new..<SNR>37_process":
Zeile   13:
E121: Undefined variable: g:vundle_last_status
E15: Invalid expression: 'error' == g:vundle_last_status
Zeile   17:
E121: Undefined variable: g:vundle_last_status
```

I removed everything in the bundle directory and I reinstalled vundle. Still it tries to execute zsh. What is wrong here?

Comment: Which default shell does vim use? Run `:set shell`.

Answer (score 1):

I'd guess that `'shell'` is still set to use `zsh`. Check with `:verbose set shell?` and disable the config / reconfigure to `:set shell=/bin/bash` in your `~/.vimrc`.

Comment: Setting the shell in my .vimrc solved the issue, but without the :

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled zsh but in my /etc/passwd it stilled referenced `/bin/zsh` instead of `/bin/bash`. So I wasn't even able to log back in to my user account after logging out/rebooting.