# Vim Vundle broken, can't open file

Tags: shell, vim, fish, vundle

My vim setup apparently has broken out of nothing. It now spills errors for every single plugin I have configured. This started happening after I have changed some appearance settings, some syntastic features (both of which I don't think are the cause) and changed my shell to fish (this MAYBE is the cause).

Using the directive `set shell=/usr/bin/fish` or `set shell=fish` does not change anything, it still fails, for which I tried after reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21404889/vim-vundle-broken-after-reverting-back-to-bash-from-zsh).

The errors happen for both `:BundleInstall` and `:BundleUpdate`. My full vimrc file is [available here](https://github.com/ranisalt/dotfiles/blob/master/vim/vimrc) if there is need to read it, it's not long.

[image]

Comment: This would be a good question for http://vi.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, setting your shell to `fish` is likely to be the root of your problem.  The `fish` shell doesn't support the standard UNIX syntax for file redirections, which breaks Vim's `system()`.  Just set Vim's shell to `sh`:

```
set shell=/bin/sh
```

You can't use the interactive features of `fish` from Vim anyway.

Comment: Yes, that did the trick. `sh` on my system is linked to `bash`, which works fine too.

Answer (score 1):

A while back I wrote up some [docs for this on the Vundle wiki](https://github.com/gmarik/Vundle.vim/wiki#i-dont-use-a-posix-shell-ie-bashsh) that you may find useful. In short, you can either:

1. Run: `env SHELL=(which sh) vim +BundleInstall! +BundleClean +qall`
2. Add `set shell=sh` to your .vimrc

As an aside, my [Tackle project](https://github.com/justinmayer/tackle) has an [Up plugin](https://github.com/justinmayer/tackle/tree/master/plugins/up) that includes a handy way to update your vim plugins via Vundle.